# Handle Undefined Object Using JavaScript Find

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I have two teams in an array which have `id` 1 and 2:

```
{
   "teams": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "England",
                "groupName": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Germany",
                "groupName": 6
            }
    ]
}
```

I have to make an API call to the backend which sometimes returns an id of 0 (which is not mapped in the array above). Here is the JSX code when I try to render it to a `Table`:

```
                        <td style={{ width: '16.66%', wordBreak: 'break-all' }}>
                            {teams.find((team) => team.id === fixture.team1Id).name}
                        </td>
```

As a result, I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` when `fixture.team1Id` is 0. How can I handle it on the front-end to return a string like "TBC" whenever `fixture.team1Id` is 0?

Comment: `{(teams.find((team) => team.id === fixture.team1Id) | {}).name}`

Comment: {(teams.find((team) => team.id === fixture.team1Id)? (teams.find((team) => team.id === fixture.team1Id).name || "TBC" }
Hope this snippet helps, you can simplify this to make it cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` method will have `undefined` when nothing found.

 Use `?.` optional chaining operator and `??` nullish coalesce operator.

```
{teams.find((team) => team.id === fixture.team1Id)?.name ?? 'TBC'}
```

Update: When dont have support for these operators

```
const found = teams.find((team) => team.id === fixture.team1Id);

{found ? found.name : 'TBC'}
```

Comment: optional changing is available in node 14 and above, a good option but will crash on the server if your server node is <14.

Comment: Good point @MUHAMMADILYAS. Updated with alternate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<td style={{ width: '16.66%', wordBreak: 'break-all' }}>
    {teams.find((team) => team.id === fixture.team1Id) ? teams.find((team) => team.id === fixture.team1Id).name : "TBC"}
</td>
```

It would be better if you can fetch the team in javascript code itself

in Javascript

```
var team = teams.find((team) => team.id === fixture.team1Id);
```

in HTML

```
<td style={{ width: '16.66%', wordBreak: 'break-all' }}>
    {team.name || "TBC"}
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring assignement with default empty object:

```js
const teams = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "England",
    "groupName": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Germany",
    "groupName": 6
  }
]

const { name } = teams.find((team) => team.id === 0) || {}

console.log(name)
```

or simply use two variables, one for found teams, one for found teams name:

```js
const teams = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "England",
    "groupName": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Germany",
    "groupName": 6
  }
]

const foundTeams = teams.find((team) => team.id === 0)
const foundTeamsName = foundTeams && foundTeams.name

console.log(foundTeamsName)
```